# how to send attachment with pear smtp

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear

I want to send a file with email using pear smtp. Email is successfully going to the email. Also an attachment is going with email but with noname and no content in it. When i download the attachment it has only one line **"This is a multi-part message in MIME format...".**

I didn't understand whats wrong with it. I have attached the code with this question that i am using to send the attachment with email. Please guys review once and let me know what's wrong with this code.

Thanks in advance.

```
require_once "Mail.php";   
include('Mail/mime.php');

$from = "Dispatcher <server@mymailserver.com>";
$host = "smtp.mymailserver.com";
$username = "mailuser";
$password = "password";
$to = "email@example.com";
$subject = "Subject of the email";

$hdrs = array ('From' => $from,
            'To' => $to,
            'Subject' => $subject,
            );


$text = 'Text version of email';
$html = '<html><body>HTML version of email</body></html>';
$file = './test.txt';

$crlf = "rn";
$mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
$mime->setTXTBody($text);
$mime->setHTMLBody($html);
$mime->addAttachment($file);

$body = $mime->get();
$hdrs = $mime->headers($hdrs);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
  array ('host' => $host,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password));

$smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

        if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
            echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
```

Comment: I have used PHP mailer to send mails and also with attachments.. once try with that.. I may work..

Comment: Your `$crlf` might not be suitable as a parameter for `Mail_mime` constructor. According to [the official document](https://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/docs/1.10.0/Mail_Mime/Mail_mime.html), it should be an associative array.

Comment: @Passerby You are awesome, now i have use the  "\n" in $crlf instead of "rn" and it is working well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$crlf` means "carriage return, line feed" and should be that.

Use `"\n"` to make it work with e-mails.